# Auto-expanding a UIView and CGPath to fit Core Text

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, core-text, cgpath

I've been searching all over stack to an answer for this, although there is a lot on the topic nothing quite seems to answer the question, at least not to me.

I have a custom UIView of fixed size in storyboard (in a prototype cell). I subclassed UIView for it and over-wrote the drawRect Method. It basically puts together a formatted string, then I draw it like so:

```
// now for the actual drawing
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, 
                            CGSizeMake(0, 1), 
                            0,  
                            [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); //1
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, self.bounds );

// flip the coordinate system
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CTFramesetterRef framesetter =
CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)stringToDraw); //3

CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);


CTFrameDraw(frame, context); //4
```

That's fine and works and if I make the default size big enough, it'll handle multiple lines of text.

The CGPath uses all of the UIView, that's fine/desired.

I want to keep the CGPath's width fixed, but I want the height to expand to accomodate an essentially unlimited amount of text, right now it just gets cut off (due to the path/view not being big enough to encompass it)

I've tried playing with CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints to no avail. Can someone please help me develop some code that will achieve what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the string to draw and the font to use, you can always get the bounds from

```
CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGSize requiredSize = [yourText sizeWithFont:yourFont
                           constrainedToSize:boundingSize
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGFloat requiredHeight = requiredSize.height;
```

You there get the height and can reuse it elsewhere...

Comment: Thanks @nicolasthenoz, although the other reason I needed it to expand to fit, was because I plan to position other elements right after/under the text. Also my table cell would expand that large too, more than is needed for the text.

Comment: `sizeWithFont` will not work accurate with CoreText, at least not in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are trying to do, note that this uses CoreText APIs and will return the proper height unlike the sizeWithFont answer which is wrong.

```
// Measure the height required to display the attr string given a known width.
// This logic returns a height without an upper bound. Not thread safe!

- (NSUInteger) measureHeightForWidth:(NSUInteger)width
{
  NSAssert(self.isDoneAppendingText == TRUE, @"isDoneAppendingText");

  NSAssert(self.attrString, @"attrString");

  CFMutableAttributedStringRef attrString = self.attrString;
  CFRange stringRange = self.stringRange;

  CGFloat measuredHeight = 1.0f;

  // Create the framesetter with the attributed string.

  CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);

  if (framesetter) {
    CFRange fitRange;
    CGSize constraints = CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX); // width, height : CGFLOAT_MAX indicates unconstrained

    CGSize fontMeasureFrameSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, stringRange, (CFDictionaryRef)NULL, constraints, &fitRange);

    // Note that fitRange is ignored here, we only care about the measured height

    measuredHeight = fontMeasureFrameSize.height;

    CFRelease(framesetter);
  }

  return (NSUInteger) ceil(measuredHeight);
}
```